# Loop in SPSS to draw sample repeatedly and get a descriptive statistics from each sample

Tags: loops, spss

I want to draw sample of size 50 for 100 times from a dataset and get a descriptive statistics from each sample in the output window. I have used the following codes, but getting warning!!!

```
loop # = 1 to 100.
USE ALL. 
do if $casenum=1. 
compute #s_$_1=50. 
compute #s_$_2=10251. 
end if. 
do if  #s_$_2 > 0. 
compute filter_$=uniform(1)* #s_$_2 < #s_$_1. 
compute #s_$_1=#s_$_1 - filter_$. 
compute #s_$_2=#s_$_2 - 1. 
else. 
compute filter_$=0. 
end if. 
VARIABLE LABELS filter_$ '50 from the first 10251 cases (SAMPLE)'. 
FORMATS filter_$ (f1.0). 
FILTER  BY filter_$. 
EXECUTE. 
DESCRIPTIVES VARIABLES=myvar1 
/STATISTICS=MEAN STDDEV VARIANCE SEMEAN.
end loop.
exe.
```

I am getting the first warning as:

```
>Warning # 142.  Command name: USE 
>LOOP has no effect on this command.
```

I am new in SPSS, and never did **loop** before.
I am using SPSS version 22.
 Any help will be appreciated. Apology if it is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to wrap the sample and descriptives commands you're trying to use in a macro:

```
DEFINE !repsample(times=!TOKENS(1) / size=!TOKENS(1) / maxn = !TOKENS(1) / vars=!CMDEND)
!DO !cnt=1 !TO !times.
do if $casenum=1.
compute #s_$_1=!size.
compute #s_$_2=!maxn.
end if.
do if  #s_$_2 > 0.
compute filter_$=uniform(1)* #s_$_2 < #s_$_1.
compute #s_$_1=#s_$_1 - filter_$.
compute #s_$_2=#s_$_2 - 1.
else.
compute filter_$=0.
end if.
FORMATS filter_$ (f1.0).
FILTER  BY filter_$.
DESCRIPTIVES VARIABLES= !vars
/STATISTICS=MEAN STDDEV VARIANCE SEMEAN.
!DOEND
!ENDDEFINE.
```

The macro above has four arguments - `times` to sample, `size` of sample, from first `maxn` of cases, and `vars` to use (accepts a list of variables separated by a space).  We can call it like so:

```
!repsample times = 100 size = 50 maxn = 10251 vars = myvar1.
```